# Roots of a polynomial with indeterminates $\cos(x), \sin(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $P(\cos(x), \sin(x))$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb R[X, Y]$ with degree $n$. I want to determine the number of roots of $P(\cos(x), \sin(x))$. Here I mean the possible values of the pair $(\cos(x), \sin(x))$, not roots in $x$. We exclude the case $P = \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) - 1$ and the ideal generated by $P$. Not sure whether this is enough but I meant to ask when we don't have this trivial case.

If we introduce the change of variable
$$ \cos (x) = \frac{ 1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \sin(x) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$
Then $P(\cos(x), \sin(x))$ can be considered as a rational function with numerator  $n(t) \in \mathbb R[t]$ having degree at most $2n$. But this would imply we could have at most $2n$ solutions for $t$. Thus at most $2n$ solutions for the pair $(\cos(x), \sin(x))$. Is this correct? However, I had a feeling that the number should be $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's basically right. You have to be a little careful in that $(\cos x,\sin x)
=(-1,0)$ isn't included in your parametrisation, but the conclusion still holds.

You do need $2n$, not $n$. You can see this even when $n=1$. For instance
$\cos x=\sin x$ has two solutions $(\cos x,\sin x)=(1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$
and $(-1/\sqrt2,-1/\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Thanks. You said "the conclusion still holds" without parametrize the point $(-1, 0)$. I did not notice this part. Could you please elaborate why?

Comment: @nicomezi: I noticed this. I should exclude this case or any ideal generated by this one. Not sure whether this is enough. I meant to ask when we don't have this particular case.

Comment: OK. Is it because $(-1,0) = \lim_{t \to\infty} (\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2})$? This means if $(-1,0)$ is a solution to $P(t)$, then $\lim_{t \to \infty} P(t) = 0$ by continuity and this would imply $P(t)$ is a zero polynomial.